# Exclude sections in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I need some versions of my text without some specific sections but I don't want to delete them, because I will need them again later. In a plain latex editor I would use `%`. Is there something in Lyx that allows me to temporarily exclude those text from the pdf creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think branches can help you with this. I've never used them, so I'll just quote the [LyX wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/HumanitiesLyX#toc4):

> Tricks with Branches
>
> Branches are chunks of text that can be "activated" or "deactivated"
>   -- turned on or off -- within document settings. Why would you want to do this? The official suggestion is to create problem sets: you might
>   put the answers to problems in a branch that can be turned off when
>   you print out problem sets for students, but turned on when you print
>   out an answer key for yourself. How can this feature be used in the
>   humanities? Below are some suggestions (followed by a sample file
>   illustrating these tricks), but first instructions on creating
>   branches.
>
> To create a branch, go to Document→Settings→Branches. Type the name of
>   a new branch into the "New" field, and click the Add button. (If you
>   like, you can select a branch in the list of Available Branches and
>   click on (De)activate to turn it on or off, or Alter color to change
>   the background color for text in that branch as it appears in the LyX
>   window.
>
> Once a new branch is created, you can designate text as belonging to
>   that branch by selecting that text and choosing Insert→Branch→[name of
>   branch]. Alternatively, you can insert the branch first and then type
>   your text.

Another option could be to add `\usepackage{comment}` to the preamble, add `\begin{comment}` in an ERT before the section, and `\end{comment}` in an ERT after the section.

Comment: Branches were exactly what I needed

Comment: There is also Insert > Note > Comment and Insert > Note > LyX Note.